# Java - IOException: Failed to open file: Access denied

Tags: java, ioexception

I've been developing some software in Java that'll be distributed for use with Windows or MacOS. I'm programming on an iMac at the moment (because of the Apple specific requirements). The following method drags a helpfile (.pdf) out of resources and copies it locally so that it can be displayed on the local machine.

```
private void mHelpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    String sourceFile = "resources/BRC2Help.pdf";
    String destFile = "brc2help.pdf";
    File f = new File (destFile);
    if (!f.exists()) {
            try {
            URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(sourceFile) ;
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
            System.out.printf("loaded pdf file from resources: %d bytes\n",f.length());
            } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.printf("loadPDF: %s\n",ex);}
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s exists: %d bytes\n",destFile,f.length());
    }

    try {
        if (f.exists()) {
                f.setReadable(true);
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                String.format("%s\n",ex),
                "Helpfile Problem?",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

This all works well enough on the Mac but gives an `IOException` on Windows 7:

`java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/Program%20Files/BRC2/brc2help.pdf. Error message: Access denied.`

Any idea what's going wrong here ? I've tried copying the .pdf file to other locations but the result is the same.

Comment: I've run into a very similar problem and it seems to have something to do with the space in the path name. Right now, I think it may be an issue with the JDK. It also happens with Desktop.open(), so maybe it's an issue with URI decoding. It works fine on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

What is the working directory for the program when running on Windows?  It is possible that the user context running the program doesn't have rights to write to `c:\Program Files\`.

You did not specify the path to the file so my assumption is that `c:\program files\brc\` is the working directory while running the program.  Since Windows Vista, you need to have full administration rights to be able to write to the `Program Files` and other directories.

**Updated: 7/1/2012**

Ok, I was able to stub out your program and run it as a main class and was able to have `Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);` open a PDF file on Windows 7.  I manually put a PDF file into the bin directory where Eclipse compiled my class file to.

I now need to try moving the class file and pdf into a subdirectory of `c:\program files\` and see if I get the access denied exception you receive.

Hum, I was able to get `Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);` open the PDF file when it was in `c:\program files\test\`, see my output below:

```
C:\Program Files\test>"\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" MyTestClass
brc2help.pdf exists: 943123 bytes

C:\Program Files\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 2035-793F

 Directory of C:\Program Files\test

07/01/2012  10:25 PM    <DIR>          .
07/01/2012  10:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/01/2012  09:55 PM           943,123 BRC2Help.pdf
07/01/2012  09:57 PM             2,391 MyTestClass.class
               2 File(s)        945,514 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  567,516,254,208 bytes free
```

What JRE are you using?  Mine is `java version "1.7.0_01" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)`

Comment: The working directory is c:\Program Files\BRC\ Writing doesn't seem to be the problem; the .pdf file gets copied to the working directory well enough ... it just can't read it. I can double-click on the .pdf file and Adobe Reader displays it perfectly.

Comment: To clarify things a little ... the JAR file is first wrapped in a exe4j wrapper the the resulting executable wrapped in an Inno setup distribution wrapper. However, if I amble along to the source folder (on my Windows PC, copied from the Mac) and start the program with "java -jar BRC.jar" it does all the right things until I ask to view the .pdf ... when it fails in exactly the same way as above.

Comment: @user1494618 Do you have any idea which of the lines of your code that you have pasted here are generating the exception?  Since you say that the file is getting written to the directory, then is it `Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);` that leads to the exception?

Comment: I've just tried wrapping Desktop.getDesktop().open(f); in a try/catch block and yes, that's what's throwing the exception ... not much else it could be really.

Comment: It's weird that you are able to write out then file, but then not be able to read from it.  My recommendation is to figure out how to change your working directory on Windows to something other than `c:\program files\...` as I have see very restrictive behavior from Windows accessing files in `c:\program files\...` (although, typically I've only seen the inability to write to that directory unless you are administrator).  Are you able to run your program using Windows "Run as administrator" option?

Comment: Tried 'Run as Administrator' ... no change.
Tried changing destFile = "C:\\brc2help.pdf\\"; ... no change.
Tried changing destFile = "C:\\ProgramData\\brc2help.pdf\\"; ... no change.
What about the '/' between 'file:' and 'C:\...." in the error message? I don't remember seeing that before? Could it be something to do with the way that the path is constructed?

Comment: I don't know how to get your level of detail but the 'release' file in Program Files>Java>jre7 says JAVA_Version="1.7.0". On the Mac; I've no idea (or how to find it); it's an Apple Special, isn't it? It looks like I'm going to have to make two versions; a Mac one developed under OSX and a Windows one under Windows ... kinda defeats the object, eh?

Comment: HeatfanJohn: I've downloaded and installed Netbeans 7.1.2 onto my Win7 PC, removed the OSX-specific code so that it'll compile and, after all that ... same problem. Not to worry, I'll change the .pdf to .html and get the users to download the helpfile instead (I know that works cross-platform). Thanks for your efforts but I'm going to have to abandon this approach for now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with HeatfanJohn, it is definitely a permission issue.

Try compiling your java code as Administrator from the command line. Simply run cmd.exe as Administrator and then try compiling/running again.

Comment: The problem is that I can't compile the code on my Windows PC because of all of the OSX-specific stuff in there - fiddling with the menu-bar, etc. - the libraries aren't available. Unless you know of a way that it can be done ...

Comment: If I look at the permissions relating to the .pdf file (that my app copied into the C:\Program Files\BRC\ directory) Windows says: SYSTEM: Full Control; Administrators:Full Control; Users: Read & execute ... and it's currently owned by Administrators (and me). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Two things bother me about the error message: (1) the '/' before the drive letter and (b) the '%20' representing the space between 'Program' and 'Files'. Are either of those things relevant do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. Don't know the reason, but found a solution.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL \"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(f.getAbsolutePath()) + "\"");
```

you should use this only if the Desktop method fails, because this is only for Windows.